# Disable GUI Browser Caching?

Tags: cme

Is it possible to turn off Tridion GUI caching (temporarily) from the browser settings?

During development and training we update Schemas and add new fields quite often and need to flush the cache and restart the browser to see the new fields in our Component screen.  Being able to disable it while we add / remove Schema fields would make it easier to see our changes reflected in our Components.

Comment: Did you try disabling browser cache? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development

Comment: Related: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/152/templates-not-readily-available-in-tridion-content-manager

Answer (score 1):

For which Tridion version is this?  If this is 2013 SP1 you can disable Tridion caching for certain objects within the Content Manager Explorer, see [SDL LiveContent](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-10627CB5-9C7F-4FFF-BEE6-97852E2C7D9F) (login required) for more details.